# Converting powershell array into table

Tags: powershell

I have an array of comma separated data that I need to do operations on.  In the past I would write to a file then Import-Csv that file back to a variable.  Is there anyway to split the data into columns?

Sample data:

```
status,lastSync,lastEnrollmentTime,serialNumber,annotatedUser,deviceId,model,orgUnitPath,macAddress,willAutoRenew,orderNumber,meid,supportEndDate,osVersion,ethernetMacAddress,bootMode,platformVersion,firmwareVersion
ACTIVE,2016-03-07T21:09:12.333Z,2015-07-07T18:05:47.849Z,LRXXXXXX,enroll@domain.org,0151f63c,Lenovo N21 Chromebook,/Devices/2nd,,,,,,,,,,
ACTIVE,2016-03-07T21:12:50.856Z,2015-10-14T18:27:36.757Z,NXSHEAAXXXXXX,enroll@domain.org,01cc8dd9,Acer C720 Chromebook,/Devices/1st,,,,,,,,,,
```

Here is the format I get when exporting to a CSV then importing back in:

```
status    lastSync    lastEnrollmentTime    serialNumber    annotatedUser    deviceId    model    orgUnitPath    macAddress    willAutoRenew    orderNumber    meid    supportEndDateosVersion    ethernetMacAddress    bootMode    platformVersion    firmwareVersion
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACTIVE    2016-03-07T21:09:12.333Z    2015-07-07T18:05:47.849Z    LRXXXXXX    enroll@domain.org    0151f63c    Lenovo N21 Chromebook    /Devices/2nd/H...
ACTIVE    2016-03-07T21:12:50.856Z    2015-10-14T18:27:36.757Z    NXSHEAAXXXXXX    enroll@domain.org    01cc8dd9    Acer C720 Chromebook    /Device...
```

Comment: What format are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = @'
status,lastSync,lastEnrollmentTime,serialNumber,annotatedUser,deviceId,model,orgUnitPath,macAddress,willAutoRenew,orderNumber,meid,supportEndDate,osVersion,ethernetMacAddress,bootMode,platformVersion,firmwareVersion
ACTIVE,2016-03-07T21:09:12.333Z,2015-07-07T18:05:47.849Z,LRXXXXXX,enroll@domain.org,0151f63c,Lenovo N21 Chromebook,/Devices/2nd,,,,,,,,,,
ACTIVE,2016-03-07T21:12:50.856Z,2015-10-14T18:27:36.757Z,NXSHEAAXXXXXX,enroll@domain.org,01cc8dd9,Acer C720 Chromebook,/Devices/1st,,,,,,,,,,
'@

convertfrom-csv -InputObject $string | FormatTable -AutoSize
```

Gives you this:

```
status lastSync                 lastEnrollmentTime       serialNumber  annotatedUser     deviceId model                 orgUnitPath  macAddress willAutoRenew
------ --------                 ------------------       ------------  -------------     -------- -----                 -----------  ---------- -------------
ACTIVE 2016-03-07T21:09:12.333Z 2015-07-07T18:05:47.849Z LRXXXXXX      enroll@domain.org 0151f63c Lenovo N21 Chromebook /Devices/2nd                         
ACTIVE 2016-03-07T21:12:50.856Z 2015-10-14T18:27:36.757Z NXSHEAAXXXXXX enroll@domain.org 01cc8dd9 Acer C720 Chromebook  /Devices/1st
```

Please let me know if this is the answer you're looking for. Your question is a bit vague.